# Writing Parquet to HDFS in Python

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I am learning to use Parquet format (thanks to this link https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html).
So, am i trying to write a Parquet file into the HDFS, but it is not working.
I have the following code :

```
`import pyarrow as pa
host='my.host'
port=8020
user='username'
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [-1, np.nan, 2.5],'two': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],'three': [True, False, True]}, index=list('abc'))
fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host, port, user=user)`
```

And this last line got me this error :

```
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hadoop': 'hadoop'"
```

I haven't found how to solve this error... So if anyone has an idea...

Thanks,
Neira

Comment: Can you please post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#hadoop-file-system-hdfs), you need to put the `bin` folder in your hadoop distribution in the `PATH`.

> By default, pyarrow.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem uses libhdfs, a JNI-based interface to the Java Hadoop client. This library is loaded at runtime (rather than at link / library load time, since the library may not be in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH), and relies on some environment variables.
>
> - HADOOP_HOME: the root of your installed Hadoop distribution. Often has lib/native/libhdfs.so.
> - JAVA_HOME: the location of your Java SDK installation.
> - ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR (optional): explicit location of libhdfs.so if it is installed somewhere other than $HADOOP_HOME/lib/native.
> - CLASSPATH: must contain the Hadoop jars. You can set these using:
>
> `export CLASSPATH="$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs classpath --glob"`
>
> If CLASSPATH is not set, then it will be set automatically if the hadoop executable is in your system path, or if HADOOP_HOME is set.
>
> You can also use libhdfs3, a thirdparty C++ library for HDFS from Pivotal Labs:
>
> ````py
> fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host, port, user=user, kerb_ticket=ticket_cache_path,
>                     driver='libhdfs3')```
> ````